# nhibernate INamingStrategy - Add className before columnName

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to add className before ID column. For Example. I have a class,

```
public class Employer {
    public long ID {get;set;}
  }
```

And May map file,

```
 <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" ... >
  <class name="Employer" >
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="sequence"  >
        <param name="sequence">Employer_Seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In INamingStrategy, there is e method to change property name ,

```
 public string PropertyToColumnName(string propertyName)
        {
            propertyName =Up(DefaultNamingStrategy.Instance.PropertyToColumnName(propertyName));
            return propertyName;
        }
```

What should I do to change ID to EMPLOYER_ID without defining it in hbm.xml file ? In the method I dont have className info.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible. But why do you think you need to change the ID to Employer_ID in the cs. If it was in the schema level, that would have made sense as when it comes to joins and so on it would be clear to have tablename_Id standard. But why in the objects?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this instead:

```
DefaultNamingStrategy.Instance.LogicalColumnName(columnName, propertyName);
```

Comment: Doesn't it map a column in a db to a property in the mapping?

Comment: I debug INamingStrategy for DefaultNamingStrategy.Instance.LogicalColumnName method. But the mothod was never called. What should I do to make NHibernate to use Method?